# Can the new Facelet Tag Libraries URI's be used in older JSF versions?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, taglib

I read somewhere that the Facelet Tag Libraries URI's changed from `http://java.sun.com/jsf/*` to `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/*`, so that means the new namespaces applies only for the new specification(JSF 2.2) or they can or should be used in older versions like 2.0, 2.1 or 1.x?

for example:

```
Library                 Old URI                             New URI
Composite Components    http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite   http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite
Faces Core              http://java.sun.com/jsf/core        http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core
HTML_BASIC              http://java.sun.com/jsf/html        http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html
JSTL Core               http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core   http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core
Facelets Templating     http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets    http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets
```

**EDIT**

To make the question more understandable nothing like a snippet of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"  
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"  
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">  
<h:head>  
    <title>test</title>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Style" href="theme/stylesheet.css" />  
</h:head>  
<h:body>  
    <h:form id="form1" styleClass="form">  
        <h:inputText id="text1" styleClass="inputText"></h:inputText>  
    </h:form>  
</h:body>  
</html>
```

The previous code would be valid for JSF 2.0? notice the taglibs:

```
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"  
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"  
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen here : http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/index.html, the canonical names for the large majority of taglibs stays `http://java.sun.com/`

However, as stated, you can use the new URIs since they created an alias.

Comment: Hi Thrax, how do you know that they created an alias?

Comment: That's what I understood from : `All new Java related schemas are created in subdirectories of this directory. The canonical name for this directory is http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/ althought it's currently hosted in a different location. Note also that many of the Java schemas from java.sun.com are hosted in the same location, although their canonical names remain http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/....`